# loop sql result based on the parameter list passed and store result in table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have parameter list like typology with value TRS:5, IRS:10 (value are separated with colon, 1st value is typology and 2nd value is records  to fetch from table)

i wanted to loop sql based on the number of parameter passed and store result in table,

so , based on parameter by below sql should loop 2 times and store result in table

```
typology1=TRS,IRS
rownumber1=5,10
for loop in ( select contract,typolgy from table ABC 
              where typology =: typology1 
                and rownum=:rownumber1)
<store value in a table>
end
```

ABC table data :

```
Contract Typolgy
123      TRS
123      TRS
123      TRS
123      TRS
123      TRS
123      TRS
1231     TRS
1232     TRS
1234     TRS
1235     TRS
1236     TRS
1237     TRS
1237     IRS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you described, you don't need a loop; `select` can do it itself.

Sample data: I modified `contract` values so that it would be easier to distinguish one from another while testing.

```
SQL> desc test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 CONTRACT                                           NUMBER
 TYPOLOGY                                           VARCHAR2(10)

SQL> select * From test;

no rows selected

SQL> select * From abc;

  CONTRACT TYPOLOGY
---------- ----------
       123 TRS
       124 TRS
       125 TRS
       126 TRS
       127 TRS
       128 TRS
      1231 TRS
      1232 TRS
      1234 TRS
      1235 TRS
      1236 TRS
      1237 TRS
      1237 IRS

13 rows selected.
```

Procedure: I don't see much sense in what you want to do, but - I guess that it is just an example of something more complex. Anyway: `regexp_substr` is used to extract the first (topology) and second (counter) part of the input parameter.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_typ in varchar2)
  2  is
  3  begin
  4    insert into test (contract, typology)
  5    select a.contract, a.typology
  6      from abc a
  7      where a.typology = regexp_substr(par_typ, '^\w+')
  8        and rownum <= to_number(regexp_substr(par_typ, '\w+$'));
  9  end;
 10  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> exec p_test('TRS:3');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From test;

  CONTRACT TYPOLOGY
---------- ----------
       123 TRS
       124 TRS
       125 TRS

SQL> exec p_test('IRS:5');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From test;

  CONTRACT TYPOLOGY
---------- ----------
       123 TRS
       124 TRS
       125 TRS
      1237 IRS

SQL>
```

---

If, as you commented, input parameter consists of several parts, then split it into smaller pieces (see `FOR LOOP` query) and then use that *piece* as I already showed.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_typ in varchar2)
  2    is
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in
  5      (select regexp_substr(par_typ, '[^,]+', 1, level) l_typ
  6       from dual
  7       connect by level <= regexp_count(par_typ, ',') + 1
  8      )
  9    loop
 10      insert into test (contract, typology)
 11      select a.contract, a.typology
 12        from abc a
 13        where a.typology = regexp_substr(cur_r.l_typ, '^\w+')
 14          and rownum <= to_number(regexp_substr(cur_r.l_typ, '\w+$'));
 15    end loop;
 16  end;
 17  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec p_test('IRS:5,TRS:4,REPO:6');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From test;

  CONTRACT TYPOLOGY
---------- ----------
      1237 IRS
       123 TRS
       124 TRS
       125 TRS
       126 TRS

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks... but parameter will something like below
exec p_test('IRS:5,TRS:4,REPO:6'). so based on typology and rownum , it should fetch data and store in table.

Comment: for l_tables in ( SELECT level,trim(regexp_substr(v_typology_reccount, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) job_id_row FROM dual CONNECT BY regexp_substr(v_typology_reccount , '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL )
  
    loop 
         v_typology := REGEXP_SUBSTR (l_tables.job_id_row, '[^:]+', 1, 1);
           v_reccount := to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR (l_tables.job_id_row, '[^:]+', 1, 2));

Comment: loop 
         v_typology := REGEXP_SUBSTR (l_tables.job_id_row, '[^:]+', 1, 1);
           v_reccount := to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR (l_tables.job_id_row, '[^:]+', 1, 2));
       v_sql_stmt :='insert into TRN_TYPOLOGY_REP(first_name,job_id) select first_name,job_id  from EMPLOYEES  where upper(job_id) = ''' || upper(v_typology) || ''' and rownum <= ' || v_reccount;
   dbms_output.put_line(v_sql_stmt); 
   execute immediate v_sql_stmt; 

           end loop; 
     commit;

Comment: You're welcome. If input parameter looks as you said, then you have to split it to smaller pieces; the rest of the procedure is the same. I edited my answer and added some more code. Have a look, please.